# Paginating a dynamic SQL result

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, pagination

i have a multiple checkboxes that filter an SQL result. I will be expecting with alot of records returned so i will like to paginate it. my current pagination code only works for simple SQL statements like `SELECT * FROM movies LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}` The issue is that i cant get it to work with my current jquery filter for my SQL result.

**Pagination function**

```
   // Pagination Function
   function pagination($query,$per_page=10,$page=1,$url='?'){   
global $conDB; 
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM movies";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conDB,$query));
$total = $row['num'];
$adjacents = "2"; 

$prevlabel = "&lsaquo; Prev";
$nextlabel = "Next &rsaquo;";
$lastlabel = "Last &rsaquo;&rsaquo;";

$page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

$prev = $page - 1;                          
$next = $page + 1;

$lastpage = round($total/$per_page);

$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1; // //last page minus 1

$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1){   
    $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";


        if ($page > 1) $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$prev}'>
  {$prevlabel}</a></li>";

    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)){   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++){
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}</a> 
    </li>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>
    {$counter}</a></li>";                    
        }

    } elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)){

        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) {

            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); 
        $counter++){
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}
           </a></li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>
      {$counter}</a></li>";                    
            }
            $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lpm1}'>{$lpm1}</a>
      </li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lastpage}'>
      {$lastpage}</a></li>";  

        } elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > 
      ($adjacents * 2)) {

            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page +
        $adjacents; $counter++) {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}
         </a></li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>
          {$counter}</a></li>";                    
            }
            $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lpm1}'>{$lpm1}</a>
        </li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lastpage}'>
       {$lastpage}</a></li>";      

        } else {

            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2));
           $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}
        </a></li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>
       {$counter}</a></li>";                    
            }
        }
    }

        if ($page < $counter - 1) {
    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$next}'>{$nextlabel}</a>
     </li>";
    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>{$lastlabel}</a>
      </li>";
      }

    $pagination.= "</ul>";        
       }

return $pagination;
}//
```

**Latest.php**

```
 $page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
 if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;

 $per_page = 2; // Set how many records do you want to display per page.

$startpoint = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;

$statement = "`movies` ORDER BY `m_id` ASC";  

            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","blabla");
       $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "blabla");


         $db_username = 'root'; 
         $db_password = ''; 
         $db_name = 'blabla'; .
         $db_host = 'localhost';

         $conDB = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, 
          $db_password,$db_name)or die('Error: Could not connect to
          database.');


         if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {

         echo "Failed to Connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
         }


        $results2 = $mysqli->query( "select distinct(m_genre) 
        from movies where movie_status = '1'");  

         while($genre_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2)){

            ?>

                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"> 
                <label> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="item_filter genre" 
            value="<?php echo $genre_data['m_genre']; ?>" <?php
            if(in_array($genre_data['m_genre'],$genre)){ echo"checked";
             } ?> >
         <span class="check-box-effect"></span>
                &nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $genre_data['m_genre']; ?>
       </label></a>

            <?php } ?>  
            </div>



            <div class="col-xs-4">
            <h3>Country</h3>
            <?php 
                $rs = $mysqli->query("select distinct(m_country) 
            from movies where movie_status = '1'");  

                while($country_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){

            ?>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="item_filter country"
        value="<?php echo $country_data['m_country']; ?>" <?php 
        if(in_array($country_data['m_country'],$country)){ 
        echo"checked"; } ?> >
                &nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $country_data['m_country']; 
             ?>     </a>
            <?php } ?>  
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4">
            <h3>Year</h3>
            <?php 
                $rs = $mysqli->query( "select distinct(m_year) 
               from movies where movie_status = '1'");  

                while($year_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){

            ?>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="item_filter year" 
                value="     <?php echo $year_data['m_year']; ?>"
              <?php if(in_array($year_data['m_year'],$year))
               { echo"checked"; } ?> >
                &nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $year_data['m_year']; ?></a>
            <?php } ?>  
            </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          </div>



            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12">
              <?php 


                 $query = "SELECT * FROM movies 
          WHERE movie_status = '1'"; 
                  //filter query start 
                  if(!empty($genre)){
                      $genredata =implode("','",$genre);
                      $query  .= " and m_genre in('$genredata') LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page} "; 
                  }

                   if(!empty($country)){
                      $countrydata =implode("','",$country);
                      $query  .= " and m_country in('$countrydata') LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page} "; 
                  }

                  if(!empty($year)){
                      $yeardata =implode("','",$year);
                      $query  .= " and m_year in('$yeardata') LIMIT 
            {$startpoint} , {$per_page} "; 
                  }
                //filter query end 

                 $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die("Error : 
   ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
  while(){

     ............................
            }
   echo '<div class= "wrap">';
   // displaying paginaiton.

   echo pagination($statement,$per_page,$page,$url='?');

   echo "</div>";
```

The current code as it is doesn't `Limit` the result and `displays all results`, if a `checkbox is checked`, the filter works but the pagination doesnt, `i.e no limit and link to next page gives the same result as the first`. Is there an easier way to paginate my filtered result or how can i fix my current code. i am open to new pagination solutions.

Comment: [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) here is a great plugin which can solve your problem. It's pretty simple and has a good documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious issue is that your filters are never applied, because $gendre, $country and $year are never passed to the function.

Assuming that you read those values correctly from the request object, look at the  tags in the HTML, you never set name attribute for either of them, so I think they are never passed to the code correctly if you use regular submit. It is a bit hard to say, because we cannot see the jQuery code, but that is where the problem is I think - in jQuery building your request parameters.

To fix paging, when you are building query like this:

```
   $query  .= " and m_country in('$countrydata') LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page} ";
```

first, add only filter:

```
   $query  .= " and m_country in('$countrydata') ";
```

and then after all filters are done, before executing your query add this:

```
   $query  .= " LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page} ";
```

For debugging purposes consider printing out the value of $query just before this line:

```
   $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

And compare them on page 1 and page 2 to see if anything sticks out as a sore thumb.

Comment: i understand what your saying, can be pick this up tomorrow. its 11pm over here lol

Comment: great answer, pointed out exactly what was missing in my code. `1.` i wasn't passing the filter to the url of the pagination that's why i kept getting all results and not the filtered one. `2.` i also changed the query as you suggested and out ` $query  .= " LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page} "; ` at the end of the query. Thanks

Comment: i will award the bounty to you in 2hours as it wont let me do that now

Answer (score 0):

Tadasbub's answer should be sufficient. I just write out the changes based on his suggestions.

```
              <?php 


             $query = "SELECT * FROM movies 
      WHERE movie_status = '1'"; 
              //filter query start 
              if(!empty($genre)){
                  $genredata =implode("','",$genre);
                  $query  .= " and m_genre in('$genredata')"; 
              }

               if(!empty($country)){
                  $countrydata =implode("','",$country);
                  $query  .= " and m_country in('$countrydata')"; 
              }

              if(!empty($year)){
                  $yeardata =implode("','",$year);
                  $query  .= " and m_year in('$yeardata')"; 
              }
            //filter query end 
             $query .= " LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page} ";
             $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Just change the query block as written over here. It should work as you expected.

BTW, the problem is only with php logic. It is not related to sql/mysql.